# detailed conditional submit preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twig

I've spent some time looking around and trying multiple solutions without luck, while attempting to streamline a form to create a pseudo bulk process.

Essentially I simply need to prevent default on a submit button, but to trigger it if several subconditions are met, at least one of which uses an ajax call.

I've tried variations of `e.preventDefault`, `$('#form').submit(false);` and I can either get the validation to occur, or the form to submit, but never both in the right places.  (for example it will submit without checking for duplicate entries)

Here's a summed up version of what I've been attempting.

This is the main variable which holds the first part of the check:

```
    var verifyValue = function() {
// this stops the form, and then things validate fine.
        $('#add-item-form').submit(false);
//but then I need to get it started again to submit valid entries


        if($('#value_of_json_array').val().length != 0){
            $('#value_of_json_array').prop("readonly", true);
            jQuery.getJSON('{{ path('query_to_get_array') }}?' +
                    $.param({barcode: $('#value_of_json_array').val()}))
                    .done(checkedValue);
        }
    };
```

This is where it is called:

```
$("#verify-value").click(verifyValue);
```

Below is a shorthand of the conditional being run:

```
    var checkedValue = function(items) {
        if(items.length == 0){

          // success conditions
        }
        else {
//this was just one attempt

            $('#form').submit(false);

                if( /* sub condition of data passed from JSON array */){
                           //condition creates new form which upon action sends AJAX call
                }
                else
                {
                    //second error condition
                }
        }
    };
```

What I'm trying to do is to have if any of the subconditions occur, to have it stop the submit button (e.g. `preventDefault` behavior) and if it does not have any of these, to allow the submission of the form

It feels like it should be simple, however no matter where I do this, including using `$(this).unbind('submit').submit()`  It doesn't work right.

Either the validation occurs correctly and nothing submits, or everything submits even if it's not supposed to.

I feel like modifying `var verifyValue` will work but I'm not sure how to get the conditional statements bound into an event.

---

**Edit:**

Okay, so I was guilty of seriously overthinking this issue, and came up with a solution which I will put below (in case anyone is interested)

Comment: Let me see if I can restate your question very simply - when a user attempts to submit a form, you desire to stop the propagation of events, validate the form (using AJAX), proceed with submission if form is valid, else do nothing (or alert the user perhaps to update their form to match some criteria)?

Comment: Sort of 1.  User attempts to submit form.  This calls a JSON array (which is fed from the app upon creation of the twig) to determine if there are any rows.  If there are rows, it first checks to see whether an item is of a certain type.  If it is, it returns a button which when clicked sends an AJAX call back to the app:  if another type; it just delivers that message:  otherwise it should simply submit the request. problem I am having is that I can either get it to run the validations, or I can get it to submit: and end up with duplicate rows and it doesn't check another important validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I was seriously overthinking this issue.  It was a lot easier to handle by binding everything into a button that was not a submit, and if it passed the validation simply use a submit condition. This way I didn't need to worry about preventing default behavior and turning it back on again (which was where I was getting stuck).  Since regular buttons have no default behavior, there was no need to be concerned about it submitting incorrectly.

The original function just needed to be simplified to:

```
    var verifyValue = function() {
        if($('#value_of_json_array').val().length != 0){
            $('#value_of_json_array').prop("readonly", true);
            $('#barcode-buttons').hide();
            jQuery.getJSON('{{ path('query_to_get_array') }}?' +
                    $.param({barcode: $('#value_of_json_array').val()}))
                    .done(checkedValue);
         }
     };

    $("#verify-value").click(verifyValue);
```

and then the check only needed to do this

```
var checkedValue = function(items) {
    if(items.length == 0){
           $('#form').submit()       
    }
    else {
        //error conditions

    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your validation includes an async step, it'd be easier to just stop the form submission right away.

Then call your validation function, which will set the validation state of the form in a "global" state (maybe just a closure of the event handler). If the validation is fine, submit the form, else just show the validation error.

```js
// You'll need to reset this if an input changes
var isFormValid = false;

$("#form").on('submit', function(e) {
  if (isFormValid) {
    return true;
  }
  
  e.preventDefault();
  
  validateForm(function(valid) {
    if (valid) {
      isFormValid = true;
      $('#form').submit();
    }
  });
});

function validateForm(cb) {
  var form = $('#form');
  
  // do some synchronous validations on the form inputs.
  // then do the async validation
  
  if($('#value_of_json_array').val().length != 0){
    $('#value_of_json_array').prop("readonly", true);
    jQuery
      .getJSON(
        '{{ path('query_to_get_array') }}?' +
        $.param({barcode: $('#value_of_json_array').val()})
      )
      .done(function(result) {
        if (checkedValue(result)) {
          cb(true);
        } else {
          cb(false);
        }
      });
  } else {
    cb(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's kind of what I was attempting with `$('#form').submit(false);`   and I could do that in the `verifyValue` piece at the top, but I couldn't get it started again.  In other words, I can stop it and validate, but then it would never submit

Comment: This is good, and definitely close to one of my attempts however my question is where specifically to call this.  Are you suggesting that it should be within `var checkedValue = function(items) `?

Comment: So is `#verify-value` not a submit button in the form? If it is, then its click event will trigger the form's `submit` event and the code above will work. Else you can just have this in the click handler of whatever button is used to complete the form.

Comment: It is the submit button.  (the id of the form itself is actually `#add-item-form`) I'm a little dizzy from the pieces.   If you note the first bit of code, do I ignore that, or is that where you meant I should put it?  The entire conditional is being held in `checkedValue` so I can't check of its existence because it contains all options including success and fail.

Comment: I have added more example to demonstrate my point. You'll probably also have to change `checkedValue` to match.

Comment: Ugh, after applying your suggestions, I got exactly the same problem I was having before The validation is occurring, but it does not submit at all. All I really need this to do is if it passes the validation to simply submit as it is supposed to.  I noticed that you declare a variable of "form" to be equal to the id of the form, however I don't see it being used again?

Comment: also, I see that it prevents the default behavior, but it seems to do it in all conditions?

Comment: The example I have is just a basic framework, don't expect it to work as-is in your case. I extracted the form element there to show that you can use it to do some synchronous validation there.

Comment: I believe you are misunderstanding how the event handler works. The event handler returns synchronously and the default behavior is executed based on the event handler's return value. So we can not make it wait for async validation to complete.

Comment: After the async validation succeeds, it sets a global flag to true then resubmits the form, which now synchronously return true because the `isFormValid` flag is turned on.

Comment: I see that there are some callbacks in there; and that makes some sense to me, however I'm having some trouble grokking it.   I guess I will need to go back to the manuals.  Thanks for the tips  (note, I'm not validating form inputs;  I'm actually just checking for the existence of any values, and then specific values in the JSON array, but I gather that doesn't really make a difference)

Comment: ended up resolving it a different way, but I very much appreciate your help, as it is a useful reference.  giving it a thumbs up

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach, here's a simple skeleton:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e){

       var formError = false;

       // set formError to true if any of the checks are not met.
       if(some condition) {
           // do a conditional check
          formError = true;
       } else if(another condition) {
          // do another conditional check
          formError = true;
       }

       if(formError) {  // stop form submission of any of the conditions are not met.
          return false; // same as e.preventDefault and e.stopPropagate()
       }

});
```

Comment: I actually did attempt to do something like that but was having the same exact problems.   (sorry it's hard to show all the examples without getting into a tl;dr situation).   If you could show where in the above code that should go, that would help a lot.  I feel like I've been going in circles.

Comment: @nomistic saw your comment above on your question , let me ask you this way , `what are the actions the user needs to perform for the form to submit successfully` .

Comment: typically it should submit fine in most cases.   However if there is an existing duplicate row, in one case they simple cancel out the transaction, and in others they simply need to click a button and move on to the next record